# NodeJs Sequelize removing properties in toJSON method leads to removed value from model itself

Tags: json, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a SequelizeInstance object which I need to omit some values when I change it into a JSON but whenever I call **delete**, it deletes that value from the SequelizeInstance as well. Here is code below:

```
instanceMethods: {
        toJSON: function() {
            var values = this.get();
            delete values.password;
            delete values.salt;
            return values;
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I called toJSON(), the SequelizeInstance will have removed the values for password and salt. A possible solution I can do is to do a shallow copy of the object and return that instead. I'm wondering is there are other better ways to approach this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Directly from sequelizer [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2132)**

```
password: {
    // ...
    get() {
        return () => this.getDataValue('password');
    }
}
```

**Authors Quote**

> Returning a function and not a value from user.password. The pros part of it is the explicit need for user.password() call to retrieve the pass. The pass will be automatically evaded by ordinary serialization too

Answer (score 0):

What I like doing is to create a method called `.publicData` like this

```
instanceMethods: {
    publicData: function () {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            publicField: this.publicField
            // do not add private fields here
        }
    }
}
```

It will basically perform a copy containing only the wanted fields. This approach is also good because you don't have to worry about updating your code every time you add a new private property because they wont be included as public data by default, you will have to manually white list them so I see this approach as security measure too

Answer (score 0):

That's correct I tried both:

```
const internalObj1 = model.toJSON()
const internalObj2 = model.get({ plain: true})
```

They both have the same issue they mutate the model reference if you change any of them.

The fix I found is deep clone their values like below:
using lodash:

```
const internalObj1 = _.cloneDeep(model.toJSON());
```

or using es5:

```
const internalObj2 = Object.assign({}, model.toJSON());
```

or using es6:

```
const internalObj3 = {...model.toJSON()};
```